# BQL query not giving the results I expect

Tags: acumatica

I have a BQL resultset consisting of several left joins, and one of the tables (ARCstRptControl) is joined multiple times under an 'alias' by way of inheriting the original DAC  The code is shown below:

```
public class ARInv : PXGraph<ARInv, ARInvoice>
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ARCstRptControl1 : ARCstRptControl { }
    [Serializable]
    public class ARCstRptControl2 : ARCstRptControl { }

    foreach (PXResult<ARTran
                      ,PMTran
                      ,ARCstRptControl
                      ,ARCstRptControl1
                      ,PMTask
                      ,Account
                      ,ARCstRptControl2> thistran in PXSelectJoin<ARTran,
                                                            LeftJoin<PMTran,
                                                                On<ARTran.pMTranID, Equal<PMTran.tranID>>,
                                                            LeftJoin<ARCstRptControl,
                                                                On<PMTran.origAccountGroupID, Equal<ARCstRptControl.accountID>>,
                                                            LeftJoin<ARCstRptControl1,
                                                                On<PMTran.accountGroupID, Equal<ARCstRptControl1.accountID>>,
                                                            LeftJoin<PMTask,
                                                                On<PMTask.projectID, Equal<PMTran.projectID>,
                                                                And<PMTask.taskID,Equal<PMTran.taskID>>>,
                                                            LeftJoin<Account,
                                                                On<ARTran.accountID, Equal<Account.accountID>>,
                                                            LeftJoin<ARCstRptControl2,
                                                                On<Account.accountGroupID, Equal<ARCstRptControl2.accountID>>>>>>>>,
                                                Where<ARTran.tranType, Equal<Current<ARInvoice.docType>>, 
                                                And<ARTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>>.Select(this))
        {
            ARTran artran = (ARTran)thistran;
            PMTran pmtran = (PMTran)thistran;
            ARCstRptControl srcgrp = (ARCstRptControl)thistran;
            ARCstRptControl1 destgrp = (ARCstRptControl1)thistran;
            PMTask pmtask = (PMTask)thistran;
            Account account = (Account)thistran; 
            ARCstRptControl2 destgrp2 = (ARCstRptControl2)thistran;
```

All the table / DAC variables have the expected results, except ARCstRptControl2.  I've moved this entire query into SQL Server and it gives me the results I want, including ARCstRptControl2 - but I must be doing something wrong with the join here in the BQL.  Any ideas?

Comment: why not check the SQL trace for the query acumatica generates.

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm using aliased DACs (ARCstRptControl1 and 2), and since I'm using two fields from those aliased DACs, I needed to have those fields (and any others that would be used) from that alias declared in the DAC declaration, as follows (i.e., I'm using accountID and columnID in the join):

```
[Serializable]
public class ARCstRptControl1 : ARCstRptControl
{
    public abstract new class accountID : IBqlField { }
    public abstract new class columnID : IBqlField { }
}
```